# Is it possible to execute a .desktop file from a quicklist?

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists

I have this launcher I created with a quicklist full of options to execute different applications. One of the options is TeamViewer and this is the quicklist code for it:

> [Desktop Action fav-teamviewer]
>   Name=TeamViewer
>   Exec=/opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/script/teamviewer
>   OnlyShowIn=Unity

This works perfectly, but what if I wanted to execute the "teamviewer.desktop" file directly? Something like this...

> [Desktop Action fav-teamviewer]
>   Name=TeamViewer
>   Exec=/usr/share/applications/teamviewer.desktop
>   OnlyShowIn=Unity

I've tried it, but it won't work. Why is it not working? Am I doing it wrongly or is it impossible to be done?

The reason I want to do it is that if I run TeamViewer normally, from the Dash, its icon on the Launcher is perfect (first image); but if I run it from that quicklist option, it loses its default icon and gets the generic Wine application icon (second image). Please, see screenshots for a better understanding.

[image: If run from the Dash:]
[image: If run from the QuickList:]

I hope you can help me. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: That's because .desktop files aren't executables. Other apps (like Unity launcher) can read them and execute specifyed programms.

Comment: I see, enedil. So... is it impossible to do it? Isn't there a workaround or a legitimate way to do it, like using "xdg-open", "gnome-terminal -x" or whatever? I don't know. Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: Use `Exec=gtk-launch teamviewer.desktop /usr/share/applications`  Instead of `Exec=/usr/share/applications/teamviewer.desktop` To launch desktop file.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a solution, but I need to understand: do you run teamviewer under wine? there is a linux version, and the command seems no to call a wine application?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Linux version is Windows version with Wine included.

Comment: Pandya, your suggestion works, but there's this odd behavior of the mouse pointer... It keeps on "working" after launching TeamViewer (or any other application), as if it were waiting for something else. I tried to run the command via terminal and noticed that the action doesn't seem to end. Here's the output when I run it from terminal: Init... Checking setup... Launching TeamViewer... And it stays like that and won't end and go back to prompt, although TeamViewer is already open and working. But it works. I'm just worried about this odd behavior. Shouldn't I? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Jacob, TeamViewer for Linux is not native; it's just packed and adapted for it. And, yes, it runs over Wine. When I launch it, there's this little Wine box that appears very quickly before the TeamViewer main window appears. :)

Comment: What you can try, and should work under "normal" circumstances, is to add a line to the `teamviewer.desktop` file: `StartupWMClass=teamviewer`

Comment: Jacob, thanks for your answer, but the problem remains. "gtk-launch" has some parameters: --class=CLASS, --name=NAME, --gdk-debug=FLAGS, --gdk-no-debug=FLAGS, --gtk-module=MODULES, --g-fatal-warnings, --gtk-debug=FLAGS, --gtk-no-debug=FLAG. I wonder if any of them can help. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: @Pandya I found this old Q&A while going through my favorites. I think you should post your comment as a proper answer. While the OP had some followup issues in their specific case, `gtk-launch` seems to be the right answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Desktop file can not be launched by directly from `Exec`. So, use **`gtk-launch`** as follows in your second file `Exec` option:

```
[Desktop Action fav-teamviewer]
Name=TeamViewer
Exec=gtk-launch teamviewer.desktop /usr/share/applications
OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

By this way you will be able to launch `teamviewer.desktop` by launching this file.

---

From `man gtk-launch`:

```
NAME
       gtk-launch - Launch an application

SYNOPSIS
       gtk-launch [APPLICATION] [URI...]
```

Reference of Use for desktop file:-

```
DESCRIPTION  
         gtk-launch takes at least one argument, the name of the application to launch.
The name should match application desktop file name, as residing in /usr/share/application, 
with or without the '.desktop' suffix.
```

Comment: @Glutanimate I added this answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't get a notification. +1 for the great answer!